# Output date in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD format in php

Tags: php, datetime

I'm building a sitemap to submit to Google for better crawling through my website.

I have a date column in MYSQL database and I want the xml tag `<lastmod>` to contain date fetched from MYSQL database in `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD` format.

**Example**

If MYSQL query returns `2015-07-29` , I want this to be printed in `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD format`. However, I don't have a time column in database and I want it to be set to 12 am according to timezone of India. I've tried to do so but get `incompatible date format` error.

Comment: So show what you've tried to do, and where you've got the error,. *Always* show the code that's not working for you.

Comment: $url->addChild('lastmod', date('Y-m-dTH:i:sP' , $row['decidedon'])); Where $row['decidedon'] contains only date.

Comment: Finally, I solved it. `echo date("c", strtotime($row['decidedon']))` . I'm first converting it to UNIX timestamp and then printing it in PHP datetime format ('c').

Comment: Please edit your failed code into the *question* rather than just a comment - ideally as a short but complete program - and then you can add an answer to your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Working with timezones in PHP is pretty easy. Below follows an example:

```
// Create a new DateTime object
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));

// Output
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

// Change timezone
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));

// Output again
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```